# How to change USB mode on the DacMagic 100

Tags: audio-interfaces

The Cambridge Audio DacMagic 100 is using USB 1. How to change to USB 2?

Note, this might also fix a problem with it not working.

Answer (score 0):

To change the USB Class, turn on the unit while already pressing the Source button (i.e. press both). One of the digital input source LEDs will illuminate to indicate the current USB setting: Digital 1 represents USB Audio Class 1.0, likewise Digital 2 is USB Audio Class 2.0.